# Vertical line between two divs alignment issues

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-float

I want the two div's to be "float-left" and "float-right" with "display : inline-block".

I do this with no problems. But now, i need to insert a vertical line between them and I do this  [here](http://jsbin.com/tofehage/1/edit) and the alignment of two div's goes wrong.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: display: inline-block doesn't make sense with float.

Comment: As per my understand "float-left" and "float-right" will throw the divs left and right. "display : inline-block" will align them side by side. I think thats right. Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: you may float both of them to left and they may appear side by side still

Comment: @AbdulAli can u explain me in lame words what exactly is the role of "float" here?

Comment: @SangameshHs float (as i understand) simply breaks the normal flow of a layout and block level objects (like a div) only takes up as much space as their contents (or if width/height is explicitly defined)

Comment: @AbdulAli In that case I do not have to use "inline -block" as mentioned in one of the answer below, since using just float in ´hr´ will fix it rt?

Comment: my answer only uses an additional div for line. but hr can probably be used same way by floating it to left like the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `float: left` to the HR.

`<hr style="width:1px;height:500px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px; float: left; margin-left: 10px;"/>`

http://jsbin.com/tofehage/3/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/tofehage/4/

Give display inline-block to hr tag also.

And there is too much of margin left and right

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it may help but please see the following:

http://jsbin.com/tofehage/12/